# Can't perform query on database

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I am getting

> Invalid query An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions error

I am trying to connect to my azure sql server using php. 
I have the following code:

```
    $serverName = "cosy.database.windows.net, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"cosy", "UID"=>"eocribin", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";

     $query = sprintf("SELECT username FROM Users 
    WHERE username=eoin");
    $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo $result;

    // Check result
    // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
    if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

Not sure if it's problem with the query or the actual permissions to the database but I do get connection successful followed by the error so I know it is connection.

Comment: seems like the user that you are using to connect the Database, doesn't have proper permission to run queries. Have you tired to connect with root user and run the script?

Comment: @M.M.H.Masud how does one connect as a root user? I am using the original credentials I put in when I created the Database on Azure! I can login using visual studio update everything but when I try to connect using the actual site I run into this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you attempted to connect to Azure SQL Server, but you used `mysql_query($query)` in your code.

To query in SQLServer, you can refer to http://php.net/manual/zh/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php.

And here is the code snippet:

```
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";

    $query = sprintf("SELECT 1 as test");
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

}
```